# how to add authorization in cxf

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I am realizing a soap client in which I consume the services of my server.
The problem is that when I send the request, I always get a 401 error.

Anyone know how to send the credentials in the header since JAX-WS?

I was following this tutorial: http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Retrive-WSDL-using-basic-authentication-td5724416.html

But I did not work

Comment: 401 - Http Error comes not from CXF/JAX-WS/SOAP
It is about HTTP Authorization Header your client must provide according to the security settings for web resource on the server (as example Servlet context path can be secured in web.xml)

Comment: Thanks @Vadmir, I solved it with the following code    `org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
        HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
        HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy(); 
        httpClientPolicy.setContentType("text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
        http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
        http.getAuthorization().setUserName("user");
        http.getAuthorization().setPassword("*password*");`

Comment: But now sends me an error in the server response. Do you know how to change the response from `text / html` to `text / xml?`  This is the error: `Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream:`

Comment: I did not work with CXF directly, only through Camel. But what is in actual response? if response or error comes from CXF JAX-WS endpoint with WSDL and WebSevice interface, contentType must be text/xml automatically. What HTTP error code did you get? is it HTTP-500 error or other? So, there are number of possibilities. By error your client expects Soap Fault in the error, but it is some html. HTML cannot be produced by CXF JAX-WS endpoint. So error generates before CXF reached (as HTTP-401 you got before) or replaced after if there is a custom page for errors defined in web.xml